# Getting NULL VALUES FROM THIRD TABLE WHEN JOINED WITH OTHER TWO TABLES

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata

I am trying to join a third table

```
"TERADATA"."PRD_DWH_VIEW_LMT"."ZZMMSPECPRO_V"
```

with the other two tables in Snowflake. However, I am getting NULL values when all three are joined.

```
SELECT*
FROM "TERADATA"."PRD_DWH_VIEW_LMT"."GSC_VAL_LIST_VIEW" AS A
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         MATERIAL, BASE_UNIT_OF_MEASURE, BOD_CODE, 
         STANDARD_PRICE, NET_WGT, WEIGHT_UNIT, 
         VOLUME, VOLUME_UNIT, PRD_CAT_MGR, Week_Of
     FROM 
         "TERADATA"."PRD_DWH_VIEW_LMT"."ECC_MATERIAL_ATTRIBUTES_VIEW" 
     WHERE 
         Week_Of = (SELECT MAX(Week_Of) 
                    FROM "TERADATA"."PRD_DWH_VIEW_LMT"."ECC_MATERIAL_ATTRIBUTES_VIEW")
         AND SALES_ORG = '2900') AS B ON SUBSTR(JOIN_KEY, 1, LENGTH(JOIN_KEY) - 3) = B.Material
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT SRLOC, PLANT, BODCODE 
     FROM "TERADATA"."PRD_DWH_VIEW_LMT"."ZZMMSPECPRO_V") AS C ON RIGHT (A.JOIN_KEY, 3) = C.PLANT 
                                                              AND B.BOD_CODE = C.BODCODE
WHERE 
    LIST_ID = 'OTO'
```

[image]

However, when I go and search for those two values from Table A and B individually in Table C- I get the results correct.

Does it something have to do I am joining Table C based on values from A and B and that's why getting NULL Values?

Comment: `ON RIGHT (A.JOIN_KEY, 3) = C.PLANT AND B.BOD_CODE = C.BODCODE`What's the datatypes of the join columns, do they match? Btw, your JOIN_KEY should be split into two columns during load...

Comment: Here are data types for all 4 columns. All are VARCHAR 
                                                                                  
ECC_MATERIAL_ATTRIBUTES_VIEW
BOD_CODE= VARCHAR(4) COLLATE 'en-ci'

ZZMMSPECPRO_V
BODCODE=VARCHAR(3) COLLATE 'en-ci'

GSC_VAL_LIST_VIEW 
JOIN_KEY=VARCHAR(50) COLLATE 'en-ci'

ZZMMSPECPRO_V
PLANT= VARCHAR(4) COLLATE 'en-ci'

Comment: Hard to tell, add `RIGHT (A.JOIN_KEY, 3)` to your Select list and check if the values exist. Are you sure the combination `PLANT,BODCODE` exist?

Comment: 1) If you have additional information (such as the data types) please add it to your question - not in comments - so that all information needed to answer your question is in one place 2) Please don't use images - add all information to your question as editable text and format it appropriately i.e. data as tables 3) Make sure you include all relevant columns e.g. your code is using A.JOIN_KEY but this is not in your screenshot (another reason not to use images)

Answer (score 0):

So if I take your SQL and just rewrite it so the sub-select feel nested who I like to see them. This is purely done to help me read the code and see what it is doing, I also removed your long table names because I plan to make some fake data to test the joins, and the long names in double quotes does not really help me think.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM GSC_VAL_LIST_VIEW AS A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
         MATERIAL, 
         BASE_UNIT_OF_MEASURE, 
         BOD_CODE, 
         STANDARD_PRICE, 
         NET_WGT, 
         WEIGHT_UNIT, 
         VOLUME, 
         VOLUME_UNIT, 
         PRD_CAT_MGR, 
         Week_Of
     FROM 
         ECC_MATERIAL_ATTRIBUTES_VIEW
     WHERE 
         Week_Of = (SELECT MAX(Week_Of) 
                    FROM ECC_MATERIAL_ATTRIBUTES_VIEW)
         AND SALES_ORG = '2900'
) AS B 
    ON SUBSTR(JOIN_KEY, 1, LENGTH(JOIN_KEY) - 3) = B.Material
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        SRLOC, 
        PLANT, 
        BODCODE 
     FROM ZZMMSPECPRO_V
) AS C 
    ON RIGHT(A.JOIN_KEY, 3) = C.PLANT 
        AND B.BOD_CODE = C.BODCODE
WHERE 
    LIST_ID = 'OTO'
```

So that is easier to think about, those two sub-selects could really be CTE's again a thing I do to help think, and `LIST_ID` implicitly comes from `a.` as does `JOIN_KEY`. But then as I do that, I see that pushing the functions used on the joins into a CTE also tidies up the thinking about what is happening.

```
WITH fake_GSC_VAL_LIST_VIEW as (

), fake_ECC_MATERIAL_ATTRIBUTES_VIEW as (

), fake_ZZMMSPECPRO_V as (

), cte_A as (
    SELECT 
        *
        ,SUBSTR(JOIN_KEY, 1, LENGTH(JOIN_KEY) - 3) as b_join_key
        ,RIGHT(A.JOIN_KEY, 3) as c_join_key
    FROM fake_GSC_VAL_LIST_VIEW
    WHERE LIST_ID = 'OTO'
), cte_B as (
    SELECT 
        MATERIAL, 
        BASE_UNIT_OF_MEASURE, 
        BOD_CODE, 
        STANDARD_PRICE, 
        NET_WGT, 
        WEIGHT_UNIT, 
        VOLUME, 
        VOLUME_UNIT, 
        PRD_CAT_MGR, 
        Week_Of
    FROM fake_ECC_MATERIAL_ATTRIBUTES_VIEW
    WHERE Week_Of = (SELECT MAX(Week_Of) 
                    FROM fake_ECC_MATERIAL_ATTRIBUTES_VIEW)
        AND SALES_ORG = '2900'
), cte_C as (
    SELECT 
        SRLOC, 
        PLANT, 
        BODCODE 
    FROM fake_ZZMMSPECPRO_V
)
SELECT
    a.* EXCLUDE (b_join_key, c_join_key)
    ,b.*
    ,c.*
FROM cte_A AS A
LEFT JOIN cte_B AS B 
    ON a.b_join_key = B.Material
LEFT JOIN cte_C AS C 
    ON a.c_join_key = C.PLANT 
        AND B.BOD_CODE = C.BODCODE
```

so with so fake data inserted:

```
WITH fake_GSC_VAL_LIST_VIEW(join_key, list_id) as (
    select * from values
        ('abcdefg','OTO')

), fake_ECC_MATERIAL_ATTRIBUTES_VIEW(MATERIAL, BOD_CODE, Week_Of, SALES_ORG) as (
    select * from values
        ('abcd','CR', '2023-09-17'::date, '2900')
), fake_ZZMMSPECPRO_V(SRLOC, PLANT, BODCODE)as (
    select * from values
        ('srloc_val', 'efg','CR') 
), cte_A as (
    SELECT 
        *
        ,SUBSTR(JOIN_KEY, 1, LENGTH(JOIN_KEY) - 3) as b_join_key
        ,RIGHT(JOIN_KEY, 3) as c_join_key
    FROM fake_GSC_VAL_LIST_VIEW
    WHERE LIST_ID = 'OTO'
), cte_B as (
    SELECT 
        MATERIAL, 
        --BASE_UNIT_OF_MEASURE, 
        BOD_CODE--, 
        --STANDARD_PRICE, 
        --NET_WGT, 
        --WEIGHT_UNIT, 
        --VOLUME, 
        --VOLUME_UNIT, 
        --PRD_CAT_MGR, 
        --Week_Of
    FROM fake_ECC_MATERIAL_ATTRIBUTES_VIEW
    WHERE Week_Of = (SELECT MAX(Week_Of) 
                    FROM fake_ECC_MATERIAL_ATTRIBUTES_VIEW)
        AND SALES_ORG = '2900'
), cte_C as (
    SELECT 
        SRLOC, 
        PLANT, 
        BODCODE 
    FROM fake_ZZMMSPECPRO_V
)
SELECT
    a.* --EXCLUDE (b_join_key, c_join_key)
    ,b.*
    ,c.*
FROM cte_A AS A
LEFT JOIN cte_B AS B 
    ON a.b_join_key = B.MATERIAL
LEFT JOIN cte_C AS C 
    ON a.c_join_key = C.PLANT 
        AND B.BOD_CODE = C.BODCODE
```

we get the one row of data we would expect!

[image]

but what this allows you todo is put more filters in place, and see what the partial values are and then see why you are not getting the results you expect.
which means you can then get the values you are expecting to join, and see then, and remove the ON clauses and check "what is happening"

```
WITH fake_GSC_VAL_LIST_VIEW(join_key, list_id) as (
    select * from values
        ('abcdefg','OTO')

), fake_ECC_MATERIAL_ATTRIBUTES_VIEW(MATERIAL, BOD_CODE, Week_Of, SALES_ORG) as (
    select * from values
        ('abcd','CR', '2023-09-17'::date, '2900')
), fake_ZZMMSPECPRO_V(SRLOC, PLANT, BODCODE)as (
    select * from values
        ('srloc_val', 'efg','CR') 
), cte_A as (
    SELECT 
        *
        ,SUBSTR(JOIN_KEY, 1, LENGTH(JOIN_KEY) - 3) as b_join_key
        ,RIGHT(JOIN_KEY, 3) as c_join_key
    FROM fake_GSC_VAL_LIST_VIEW
    WHERE LIST_ID = 'OTO'
        AND JOIN_KEY = 'abcdefg'
), cte_B as (
    SELECT 
        MATERIAL, 
        --BASE_UNIT_OF_MEASURE, 
        BOD_CODE--, 
        --STANDARD_PRICE, 
        --NET_WGT, 
        --WEIGHT_UNIT, 
        --VOLUME, 
        --VOLUME_UNIT, 
        --PRD_CAT_MGR, 
        --Week_Of
    FROM fake_ECC_MATERIAL_ATTRIBUTES_VIEW
    WHERE Week_Of = (SELECT MAX(Week_Of) 
                    FROM fake_ECC_MATERIAL_ATTRIBUTES_VIEW)
        AND SALES_ORG = '2900'
        AND MATERIAL = 'abcd' -- INSERT YOUR KNOWN EXISTING value here
), cte_C as (
    SELECT 
        SRLOC, 
        PLANT, 
        BODCODE 
    FROM fake_ZZMMSPECPRO_V
    WHERE plant = 'efg' -- INSERT YOUR KNOWN EXISTING value here
)
SELECT
    a.* --EXCLUDE (b_join_key, c_join_key)
    ,b.*
    ,c.*
    ,a.b_join_key = B.MATERIAL as JOIN_1_1
    ,a.c_join_key = C.PLANT as JOIN_2_1
    ,B.BOD_CODE = C.BODCODE as JOIN_2_2
FROM cte_A AS A
LEFT JOIN cte_B AS B 
    --ON a.b_join_key = B.MATERIAL
LEFT JOIN cte_C AS C 
    --ON a.c_join_key = C.PLANT 
    --    AND B.BOD_CODE = C.BODCODE
```

gives:

[image]

So if you set of known exists but not sure why the join fails is small, the above (once you revert to removing the `fake_` parts will show what values you have, and why they do not match.